# Constructing probability space for iids

Tags: probability-theory

> When one states let "$X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots $ be a sequence of i.i.d. " What is the probability space in which this exist? i.e. what is the explicit sample space?

For example, when one writes $X \sim U[0,1]$ we have a r.v. $X$ defined $X(\omega)=\omega$ on $\Omega = [0,1]$. So how do I create independent $X_i$ all with same dsitribution on same sample space but are independent?

(I would like to also see a rigorous proof of their independence.)

Comment: A uniform variable in $[0,1]$ is a random infinite string of zeros and ones. An infinite list of independent uniforms in $[0,1]$ is an infinite square of random zeros and ones. There's a well known way to take an infinite string and use it to fill out an infinite square https://goo.gl/images/HrBmN4

Comment: Hint (for finite collection)  : For random variables taking values in $S$, $i\in\{1,2\}$
$\mathbf P[X_i\in A]=\mathbf E[\mathbf 1(X_i\in A)]=\int_{S}\mathbf 1(x\in A)\mathbf P\circ X_i^{-1}(dx),
$
 and independence gives $\mathbf P[X_1\in A, X_2\in B]= \mathbf P[X_1\in A]\mathbf P[X_2\in B]$, $A,B $ in your $\sigma$-algebra on $S$.

Comment: A general construction of i.i.d. random variables uses infinite products of probability spaces or Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem. An i.i.d. sequence with a given distribution can be constructed on the space $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ with its Borel sigma algebra and a probability measure constructed using one of the above two theorems.